# :limit number of rows found in a collect (has_many association)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, collections, limit, has-many-through

**Category**

```
has_many :products
has_many :deals, :through => :products
```

**Product**

```
has_many :deals
```

I want to display a limited number of deals on a category page.

**In categories_helper.rb:**

```
def deals
 @category.products.collect { |c| c.deals}.flatten
end
```

**In the show.html.erb (Category):**

```
<% for deal in deals  %>
 <%=  deal.name %>
<% end %>
```

This works fine, BUT it obviously throws out all deals for the products in that category and I want only 8 of them. **So I would like to apply a (:limit => 8) to the .collect. I just can't figure out where it would go.** Also I would like to do a second find with an (:offset => 8) which I'll show only on request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the `collect` since you have the `has-many-through` association. I believe this is what you're looking for:

```
@category.deals.all(:limit => 8)
```

Comment: Outch! That's a lot simpler than the knot in my brain had figured ... Thanks a lot! Val

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
@category.products.find(:all, :limit => 8)
```

Comment: Hi Can, thanks for the reply, but I am trying to get to the deals associated with the products, that's wha I do the collect.

Comment: @val_to_many: you can add `.collect` to this, I'm updating my answer.

Comment: wait a second, do you want 8 deals or 8 products?